# Polling AWS parameter store

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I'm planning to use the parameter store to have some dynamic config (property) that will programmatically get updated. The apps using this config will poll for the change every 5 minutes. Is this a good use case to use a parameter store? The config is expected to be updated once in a month or so and read like 10 times every 5 minutes. The rate at which it is being read is not expected to increase.

Answer (score 1):

It sound like your situation is:

- A config is being used by multiple apps
- The config could update *at any time* (but not very often)
- The apps should use the latest config

If the apps need to use the latest config at all times, then the only reliable method is to check the config *before every use*. If you are willing to allow some leniency, then they could update at regular intervals rather than every time the config is required.

There are several places the config could be stored:

- In a database
- In an Amazon S3 object
- In Parameter Store (as you have suggested)

Assuming that you are using a **standard parameter** (not an Advanced parameter), then there is no charge for the API calls nor the storage. Thus, using Parameter Store seems perfectly valid if it meets your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The [AWS Documents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/ssm.html#limits_ssm) states the below, so I'd say it depends on what else you're using the Parameter Store for, but you're way off the 40 requests per second.

**Max throughput (transactions per second)**

Default throughput: 40 (Shared by the following API actions: GetParameter, GetParameters, GetParametersByPath)

Higher throughput: 100 (GetParametersByPath)

Higher throughput: 3000 (Shared by the following API actions: GetParameter and GetParameters)

Answer (score 0):

Parameter Store is an event source for cloudwatch events. It would be better to try and use cloudwatch events to trigger a lambda to update config that these apps depend on.

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/organize-parameters-by-hierarchy-tags-or-amazon-cloudwatch-events-with-amazon-ec2-systems-manager-parameter-store/